# What makes submenus in Google results

Tags: seo

I noticed that when one searches for some companies in Google, the results come back with nice categories. For example, if you Google *sqlteam*, the result contains SqlTeam website sections such as Forums, SQL Server Version, Weblogs, SQL Server Links, etc.

When I Google for the site *whatiftoptions*, I don't get these nice categories. What do I need to do in order for Google to display categories in search result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, only Google knows the exact method for generating Sitelinks for your site. It is kept secret to prevent sites from abusing the ranking system, as having a site with Sitelinks can easily improve its image in the search results. Commonly sitelinked sites have the following attributes:

- Site ranks first for the keyword(s) that generate the Sitelinks listing
- Easily spiderable, structured navigation.
- Fairly high natural search traffic.
- High click through rates from the search results page.
- Popular internal pages appear as Sitelinks.
- Unique titles and meta descriptions on internal pages.

You can read more about this at http://www.hochmanconsultants.com/articles/sitelinks.shtml